# invertibility of $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible $n\times n$ real matrices. Assume that $A+B$ is invertible. Show that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is also invertible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that
$$
A(A^{-1} + B^{-1})B = A + B.
$$
Since $A + B$ is invertible, all matrices on the left have to be invertible.